# How to achieve an quantity summed up object list where the name of object is same in java stream collect operation avoiding toMap

Tags: java, java-stream, classcastexception, collect, accumulator

I'm trying to get the **quantity** of the object **summed up if the name** of the object **matches**.

The POJO details are as below:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class InventoryDetail {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
}
```

The code is as follows:

```java
public class InventoryDetailsCollationUpdateQuantityForSameName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<InventoryDetail> inventoryDetails = Arrays.asList(
                new InventoryDetail("iPhone", 1),
                new InventoryDetail("Samsung", 1),
                new InventoryDetail("iPhone", 2),
                new InventoryDetail("Motorolla", 1),
                new InventoryDetail("Nokia", 1),
                new InventoryDetail("iPhone", 1)
        );

        Function<Object, InventoryDetail> objectToInventorySkuDetailsFunction = o -> (InventoryDetail) o;

        //This works but want to know the other way to do with the .collect
        List<InventoryDetail> listFromToMap = inventoryDetails.stream()
            .map(objectToInventorySkuDetailsFunction)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(InventoryDetail::getName,
                Function.identity(),
                (is1, is2) -> {
                    is1.setQuantity(is1.getQuantity() + is2.getQuantity());
                    return is1;
                }))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(stringInventoryDetailEntry -> stringInventoryDetailEntry.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(listFromToMap);

        ArrayList<Object> listFromCollect = inventoryDetails.stream().collect(ArrayList::new,
            (list, newInventorySkuDetail) -> {
                if (list.isEmpty() || list.stream().map(objectToInventorySkuDetailsFunction)
                        .noneMatch(existingInventorySkuDetail -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(existingInventorySkuDetail
                            .getName(), newInventorySkuDetail.getName()))) {
                    list.add(inventoryDetails);
                } else {
                    list.stream()
                        .map(objectToInventorySkuDetailsFunction)
                        .filter(existingInventorySkuDetail -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(existingInventorySkuDetail
                            .getName(), newInventorySkuDetail.getName()))
                        .forEach(existingInventorySkuDetail -> existingInventorySkuDetail
                            .setQuantity(existingInventorySkuDetail.getQuantity() + newInventorySkuDetail.getQuantity()));
                }
            }
            , (l1, l2) -> {
                l2.stream()
                    .map(objectToInventorySkuDetailsFunction)
                    .forEach(inventorySkuDetailToBeChecked -> {
                        if (l1.stream().map(objectToInventorySkuDetailsFunction)
                                .anyMatch(areInventorySkuDetailSame(inventorySkuDetailToBeChecked))) {
                            l1.stream()
                                .map(objectToInventorySkuDetailsFunction)
                                .filter(areInventorySkuDetailSame(inventorySkuDetailToBeChecked))
                                .forEach(existingInventorySkuDetail -> existingInventorySkuDetail
                                    .setQuantity(existingInventorySkuDetail.getQuantity() + inventorySkuDetailToBeChecked.getQuantity()));
                        }
                    });
            }
        );
        System.out.println(listFromCollect);
    }

    private static Predicate<InventoryDetail> areInventorySkuDetailSame(InventoryDetail newInventoryDetail) {
        return existingInventoryDetail -> StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(existingInventoryDetail.getName(), newInventoryDetail.getName());
    }

    private static Consumer<InventoryDetail> addToQuantityAsNeeded(InventoryDetail inventoryDetailToBeChecked) {
        return existingInventoryDetail -> existingInventoryDetail.setQuantity(existingInventoryDetail.getQuantity() + inventoryDetailToBeChecked.getQuantity());
    }
}
```

The expected output is as below from listFromToMap, but I need to get it in listFromCollect. Please help me understand what the issue is

> [InventoryDetail(name=Apple, quantity=4), InventoryDetail(name=Samsung, quantity=1), InventoryDetail(name=Nokia, quantity=1), InventoryDetail(name=Motorola, quantity=1)]

When trying to run the above code I get the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to com.learning.java.pojo.InventoryDetail
    at com.learning.java.eight.stream.InventoryDetailsCollationUpdateQuantityForSameName.lambda$main$0(InventoryDetailsCollationUpdateQuantityForSameName.java:23)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1359)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.noneMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:459)
    at com.learning.java.eight.stream.InventoryDetailsCollationUpdateQuantityForSameName.lambda$main$6(InventoryDetailsCollationUpdateQuantityForSameName.java:42)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$4ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:220)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:510)
    at com.learning.java.eight.stream.InventoryDetailsCollationUpdateQuantityForSameName.main(InventoryDetailsCollationUpdateQuantityForSameName.java:39)
```

Please help me with a clean way to get the list of `InventtorySku` with summed up quantity if the name is the same.

Comment: What's wrong with using `toMap`? Using `collect` here becomes very messy, as you can see.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with toMap, for learning purposes wanted to know how to implement it a hard/messy way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a typo in the `if` branch of the accumulator function:

```
list.add(inventoryDetails);
```

should be

```
list.add(newInventorySkuDetail);
```

Otherwise you would be adding an `Arrays.ArrayList` to the list, but you expect the list to only contain `InventoryDetail`s . That's why the `ClassCastException` is thrown.

If you had added the correct thing, you don't need to cast at all. You can delete `objectToInventorySkuDetailsFunction` entirely.

Your `combiner` function is also incorrect. You are supposed to *merge* the entirety of `l2` into `l1`, but you are ignoring all the items in `l2` that does not also exist in `l1`.

In any case, for learning purposes, I would collect to a `Map` instead of a `List`. It is easier to write the accumulator and the combiner (you can just use `merge`).

```
BiFunction<InventoryDetail, InventoryDetail, InventoryDetail> merge = (detail1, detail2) -> 
        new InventoryDetail(detail1.getName(), detail1.getQuantity() + detail2.getQuantity());

Collection<InventoryDetail> listFromCollect = inventoryDetails.stream().collect(
        HashMap<String, InventoryDetail>::new,
        (map, detail) -> map.merge(detail.getName(), detail, merge),
        (m1, m2) -> m2.forEach((name, detail) -> m1.merge(name, detail, merge))
).values();
```

Notice that both of your approaches changes the existing `InventoryDetail` objects. I changed that in the implementation above to create new `InventoryDetail` objects instead.

Also note that your code using `toMap` doesn't need the second stream. You can get the values of the map using `values()`:

```
BinaryOperator<InventoryDetail> merge = (detail1, detail2) ->
        new InventoryDetail(detail1.getName(), detail1.getQuantity() + detail2.getQuantity());
Collection<InventoryDetail> listFromToMap = inventoryDetails.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                InventoryDetail::getName,
                Function.identity(),
                merge))
        .values();
```

If you need to convert it to a `List`, simply do `new ArrayList<>(listFromToMap)`.